# Exporting and Printing of excel file with nested tables or table within a cell

Tags: javascript, excel, datatable

I'm using dataTables and I it works perfect in displaying and exporting tables to excel files. It can also display nested tables or table within a single cell, the problem is when you export that table it returns a single line of text for each table in a cell.

Here's the actual preview and export: 
[Preview as  table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnsWv.png)
[Exported excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUuWS.png)

Comment: *1)* please provide code for your question, not hidden images *2)* Yes, dataTables only export the actual table, not injected dynamic content *3)* An Excel file with nested tables does not really make sense, at least from a Spreadsheet point of view.

Comment: Thank you sir, I'm new here. I really need to use nested tables, I used jquery data-table in standard way with export and print button. Just wondering if there's a way to deal with nested tables.

Comment: No, it has been asked multiple times over the years, also on the [**dataTables forum, and answered by the author himself**](http://www.edtor.datatables.net/forums/discussion/33988/exporting-not-working-for-nested-tables).